# No way to disable Mission Control gesture?

Tags: macos, multi-touch

Not sure if this is a bug or not in OS X Lion. By changing default gesture of mission control to use four fingers, which seems to me doesn't work. It doesn't disable it when I uncheck the gesture option either.

I miss the space id icon on taskbar and three fingers left swipe for backwards.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Disabling the gesture in the preferences works for me.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to disable the gestures in the preferences. Sometimes a reboot is needed if other things are going wrong, but on most macs the change is immediate.